# Numbers as variable names not recognized by statsmodels.formula.api

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels

Consider the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
df = DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4]})
df2 = DataFrame({'177sdays': [1,2,3], 'b': [2,3,4]})
```

Then 
    `smf.ols('a ~ b', df)
     smf.ols('177sdays ~ b', df2)`

And the first work and the second does not. The only difference seems to be the presence of numerical characters in the variable name. Why is this?

Comment: In particular it generates error invalid syntax!

Comment: ... valid python names cannot begin with numbers. Perhaps under the hood there is an eval in statsmodels. Try prefixing with underscore.

Comment: `Q` can "quote" arbitrary variable names http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtins-reference.html#patsy.builtins.Q

Comment: @Josef what if there is a variable named Q which conflicts with the Q function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, `statsmodels` uses a library called `patsy` to interpret the formulas passed to `ols`. From the [docs](http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/formulas.html), an expression of the form:

```
y ~ a + a:b + np.log(x)
```

will construct a patsy object of the form:

```
ModelDesc([Term([EvalFactor("y")])],
      [Term([]),
       Term([EvalFactor("a")]),
       Term([EvalFactor("a"), EvalFactor("b")]),
       Term([EvalFactor("np.log(x)")])])
```

[`EvalFactor`](http://patsy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/API-reference.html#patsy.EvalFactor) then "executes arbitrary Python code." Thus your variable names must be valid Python [identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers). I.e. 
the uppercase and lowercase letters A through Z, the underscore _ and, except for the first character, the digits 0 through 9.

Comment: This was super helpful.  Otherwise it's a "gotcha" with an utterly vague error message.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As @Josef stated one can use patsy `Q` to quote the variable:

```
smf.ols('Q("177sdays") ~ b', df2).fit()
```